# First edit was not checked agains code percent

Tags: bug

I was trying to answer a question; it had a code snippet about 10-20 lines long, badly formatted, so I tried to reformat it better, but when I tried to "Save Edits", it refused with something like "Your edit are mostly code, try add more comments".

But this is not my post. I am trying to edit someone else's post; if the original got posted, why would my edit cannot?
Is this by intention or maybe a bug?

Comment: A link to the post would be useful.

Comment: [assuming it is a newish question] the question is probably badly formatted, because the user mangled the formatting until the system let them post it.

Comment: The question is already posted so it would passed the system validation. I was editing it.

Comment: The post was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517376/why-error-for-realloc-error-aborted-core-dumped

Comment: Not exactly the same because the first edit was able to submit.

Comment: To anyone cared, this is not a duplicate of the marked post.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36517376/revisions) you can see that a +2k user (without need to get edits through peer review) edited the question and already formatted the code.

The original question could be posted because the OP didn't code formatting correctly and the system didn't detect it as such.

For +2k users there's no restriction to post too much code in ratio to normal text.

---

Regarding the doubts from your comments:

> Why the 1st edit *has gone through* for peer review?

It didn't. [The edit was rejected from the community mod](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11954772), which probably means the engine rejected it because of the earlier edit, and there wasn't any substantial improvement over that one.

The next hurdle to take is the one I mentioned above.

Comment: This is somehow what confuse me as well, since I made twice edits of that post, the first time it succeeded to save, no such to much code error, it was the second time, I could not save. Both were same reformatting changes.

Comment: Sorry I could not find my 1st edit link, it was removed by the Community bot because it says another use is editing it as well.

Comment: @fluter: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Do you mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11954772)? You can always find the stats of your sugeested edit, votes, reviews and other stuff in [your activity page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/436559/fluter?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: Yes, thanks. So what's the reason of the problem?

Comment: I mean why the first edit was ok, but the second errors out

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I'm sorry but when I say could not edit, I mean on the client side, in the browser, I was able to click the "Save Edits" button the first time, be it gone through for peer review or not, that is not my question. It is showed on the suggested edit page is exactly the proof about this. However the second time it could not simply click the "save edits" button.

Comment: I'm not asking about why my edit could make the peer review, I'm asking about the different behavior of the 2 edits, on the client side, regarding the "save edit" button.

Comment: My question is exactly as you said: why "the system didn't detect it as such"?

Comment: Does that means the system failed to do its validation?

Comment: @fluter No, it didn't fail on that validation, but it wasn't done for your 1st edit at all, since it was immediately invalidated because the other edit was applied before.

Comment: Why wasn't it done for the 1st edit? Do you mean something like if (other user editing) {skip code checking}?

Comment: @fluter Yes, that is exactly was happened, the other user's edit was immediately accepted, and thus yours wasn't checked any further.

Comment: Is this by design or a slip in the code?

Comment: @fluter I'd say it's by design. I can't see any slip there. Why should the engine apply further checks on edits that won't get through anyway?

Comment: I see, thank you for your patience, is it possible to remove the duplicate marker because what I asked isn't really that question earlier.